# PCA for ellipse fitting

Tags: opencv, image-processing, pca, depth

I have a depth video stream (grayscale) of a pen and pen-like objects. Since they are mostly of an ellipse shape, I want to fit an ellipse using PCA and get real-time output of ellipse angles.
The final goal is to estimate object(ellipse) orientation with respect x-y coordinate system.
Here are the image samples:
[Depth Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUK58.png)

I have read [this paper](https://dspace5.zcu.cz/bitstream/11025/916/1/Wijewickrema.pdf) on using PCA for ellipse fitting but I am not sure how to apply it.

Comment: Have a look at: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html

Comment: Also this tutorial may help you. There example with ellipse fitting
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d62/tutorial_bounding_rotated_ellipses.html